# how to read files which is having japanese context using perl script?

Tags: perl, search, unicode, cpu-word

i want to search for a word(which in ***Japanese***) in some group of files which is having ***Japanese*** context.

i tried to do as normal files, but i am getting error like ***wide character in print at line no --print statement line***.

i used

```
   use Unicode::Japanese;
   use Unicode::Japanese qw(PurePerl);
```

as given in some websites.

here is the code what i am using

```
    my $dr="My_Directory" ;    
    opendir DIR, $dr ;    
    my @txtfiles=grep { /\.txt$/ } readdir(DIR) ;    
    foreach $file(@txtfiles)    
    {       
        my $count=0;    
        my @words=();
        open(FILE, $dr.$file);
        while (<FILE>) 
        {
            push(@words, split(/\s+/));                
        } 
        foreach $word (@words) 
        {
            if($word=~ m/$word_to_search/i) 
            {                        
                $count++;                   
            }        
        }
        print "$word_to_search occurs $count times in $file file\n";  
    }
```

any ideas will be great helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

**PNVR**

Comment: What error are you getting? Which encoding is the file in?

Comment: file is in ANSI format, but i changed it int unicode and utf-8 then also i am getting error. The error is invalid syntax in line no--   push(@words, split(/\s+/));  -- but it is correct syntax for normal(english) files and it is working fine.    Is there any other syntax of japanese files.   thanks for reply

Comment: i added  **binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";** , then **"wide character in print" error solved**, but file content(Japanese text) is not printing properly. some unknown symbols are printing.

Answer (score 3):

Please first read http://p3rl.org/UNI and apply the advice given there. The topic of **encoding** has come many times on Stack Overflow already, this is not specific to Japanese at all. ([Google](http://google.com/search?q=perl+encoding+site:stackoverflow.com), [SO tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl+encoding), [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=perl+encoding))

You mention that you saved a file as UTF-8. To get you started quickly, this is a way to read one:

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'filename.txt';
```